# How to shorten "look at"?

Tags: abbreviations

I need to find a shortened format (abbreviation) for the words "look at" (to be used when referring people to another website).

For example:

> Example given → e.g

Comment: e.g. means "for example," not "example given." How about "see?"

Comment: RE: as show for regard/related

Comment: If *compare (with):* or *for reference, see:* you may like to use ***cf.*** that we commonly use in formal writing. *The division into phases is common (**cf.** Hopkins and Burton 1983; Badian 1990a).* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cf.

Comment: small addition to e.g. : it means exempli gratia, and _in English_ it may get pronounced as "for example". But indeed, the "example given" is a (common?) misinterpretation of the abbreviation.

Comment: Instead of 'look at example.com', try 'visit example.com'.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't see how the "example" relates to the question.

Comment: if you want to refer others to another page or site, all you need to do is create a hyperlink to that page. The hyperlink is the html-way to refer someone to another site. No need for "cf" or "See" or anything else. Just a link created from the relevant words in the text.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Just in case any of us didn't know what an abbreviation is, I guess. :)

Comment: There is no real way of answering this question properly without more context. Why and in what context are you telling people to ‘look at’ another website? For comparison? For reference? For different reasons altogether?

Comment: As a minor point:  With regard to a website, the easiest way to reference a website is with a hyperlink.  [*e.g.* This question has been asked on English Language and Usage.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146279/how-to-shorten-look-at)

Comment: @DavidM My website is a bit complicated, so I'm afraid that's not possible. Instead I'm using a bolded word with a title.

Comment: *e.g.* stands for _"exemplī grātiā"_ which is Latin for _"for example"_. It does not stand for _"example given"_.

Comment: What about 'watch'? Depends on context though.

Comment: I suppose *look't* is not what you are after...

Comment: Considering that this question has 11 upvotes, it looks like people aren't finding it "unclear" at all. It should be reopened.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the past, the abbreviation *cf* was used in texts. It's short for Latin *confer*, meaning 'compare'. You could still use it, but not everyone will understand it. Probably the best answer now is simply *See*.

Comment: I use cf. on an almost daily basis! I have never considered it something not everyone would understand…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet yes, but your field is linguistics, what'd you expect?

Comment: This is where I found it: http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/eg_ie.htm

Comment: I use cf in pretty much every single document I write to refer to an external source, and I do hope people reading me do understand it (even without latin, the context is quite sufficient)

Comment: Why not just the reference itself? Does _cf_ add anything? I don't think the Harvard Referencing System requires it.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, there’s a difference between simply putting a reference in brackets (which implies that the previous statement, fact, or data is taken directly from the source referenced) and including _cf._ (which implies that a similar concept or notion may be found in the source referenced, but does not imply origin). In an academic paper, including a _cf._ when you are actually attributing data to someone is, in theory, tantamount to plagiarism.

Comment: I know it's still used in that way, but it does seem rather dated, like _ibid_.

Comment: Strictly, *cf* indicates a comparison which accords with the thing in the current text; that exists in distinction with *cp* which is used for things which differ.

Comment: I recommend 'cf.' when the idea is 'compare this similar <argument/idea>'; but when it is dissimilar, I'd suggest using 'but cf.' in the sense of 'but compare this not-similar <argument/idea>'.  To use 'cf.' to mean 'see' generally is, I think, a slight misuse.

Comment: Modern usage on a website prefers see. *cf* is too formal for that usage.

Answer (score 34):

Probably the best way of shortening *Look at* is to use ***see***.

> See [ELU Stack](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

*See* is idiomatic; *look at* is not generally used to direct people's attention to other resources in this way. *Look at* **is** used in speech ("Look at that!"), and it's interesting that *see* usually appears in writing.

[Note too that *e.g.* does not mean "example given"; it means *exempli gratia,* "for the sake of example".]

Comment: Next you'll be telling us that "QED" at the end of a mathematical proof does not mean "quite easily done."

Comment: Exempli Gratia means 'for example'.  'For the sake of example' would be more along the lines of 'Pro exemplo'.

Comment: OED: "**exempli gratia** *phr.* For the sake of example; for instance. Freq. abbreviated to *e.g.* (see *e.g. adv.* at Initialisms), occas. *ex. gr.*" (which I would say was *ex gratia* but each to his own).

Answer (score 21):

The latinate abbreviation (corresponding to "e.g." for *exempli gratia*) is ["**q.v.**" for *quod vide*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/q.v.) = "which see", to direct someone elsewhere for further information. If it's an **abbreviation** you want, that's the perfect fit.

As other answers point out, however, "see" is even shorter, and provides more clarity. While "q.v." is common enough in some academic writing, it's not exactly common parlance.

My own sense is that "cf." should **not** be used here (even though it is in the "accepted" answer): it has a real meaning, and [that meaning is "compare"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cf.). From the question, that isn't the intended meaning. It is properly used in situations to *contrast* one thing with another (see also the advice from the [the APA blog](http://j.mp/1eLRU5F) on the use of "cf.").

Comment: It’s hard to tell what exactly the asker is looking for. _Q.v._ would not be suitable, for example, if he wanted to include the name or address he was referring people to.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I agree: the original "use case" is not clear to me, although "q.v." strikes me as the "correct" abbreviation of the type given as a model. Whether it ought to be used is a different matter. ;) Ah well!

Comment: I think _c.f._ is for compare, and _c.t._ is for contrast!

Comment: @martinf - It's not "c.f." but "cf.". See the link in my answer. I have never seen the *latinate* abbreviations "c.f." or "c.t.". Do you have a source? Perhaps my use of "contrast" was a bit strong. But "cf." is not simply for pointing to a source, but acknowledging some difference, comparison, or contrast from whatever precedes. Example: "Bloggs says lorem ipsum (but cf. Baggs who says foobar)". That sort of thing. (Also, see [this comment](http://j.mp/1d8WOF3) elsewhere in this Q&A.)

Comment: And at the risk of belabouring this, the [APA blog](http://j.mp/1eLRU5F) offers some trustworthy advice on the use of "cf." (among others). I'm still surprised the accepted answer is accepted, and that it has attracted to many up votes.

Comment: I should have been more careful. It's "cf." as you say and "ct," (note the comma not a period) as my sources say. I googled "abbreviation ct contrast cf confer -cat -scan" and got many biblical works. I don't remember where i discovered "ct," -- it was over 20 years ago -- but i know it wasn't from anything theological!

Answer (score 7):

So, you want to say for example

> look at my new website!

?

You can also just say

> See my new website.

if you want to shorten it.

Comment: Actually I have a bolded word, and when you hover over it it tells you to "See page X". But this works for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're bored of "see," consider "view."